# Query Powershell Error Object Time Occured

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-v4.0, error-handling

Powershell error objects contain a lot of data but I can't seem to track down the time of occurrence for a given error.  Using `$Error[0] | fl -f` retrieves a lot of information but none that appears to be a date time of when the error was generated.  It occurs to me this data would/should be part of the error object and I'm just not able to find the exact property.

I could get a close approximation by using try/catch blocks and capturing time then, but I need as precise  of a time stamp as is possible.  Anyone know where/if the time of occurrence is stored in the $Error object?

Comment: I just spent a half hour going through every object within the error array, and was unable to find it :( Starting to think it's not in there.

Comment: I've submitted the suggestion to microsoft to include a datetime property.  Please vote https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/18475576-include-utc-timestamp-as-property-to-error-object

Comment: Voted for it, I agree it's probably a good quick win addition to the object.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no date-time that is part of the error object.  If you want the datetime, just add a `Get-Date` into your `catch` block or whatever and add it to your output, logs whatever output method you are using for the rest of the error.

The 'o' format has lots of precision and useful format for log files.

```
PS C:\users> Get-Date  -Format o
2017-02-27T11:57:31.3946789-08:00
```

Comment: +1. If the execution is remote one can store all log objects to return in an arraylist. Thus one can store multiple log entries including $arrayobjects[x].error and $arrayobjects[x].time and whatever other properties in one comprehensive object to pass back (return $arrayobjects). At the receiving end this is processed into n entries of whatever log format desirable. For this reason I like passing raw datetime objects as they are so easy to post process.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell error objects don't contain date/time information.

Source: [Windows PowerShell Error Records](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714465.aspx)

The [InvocationInfo class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.aspx) doesn't contain that information either.

If you want that metadata, you'll need to put it somewhere when you `catch` a terminating error. This won't help too much with non-terminating errors, though.

It might help if you more fully explain your use case.

Comment: Couldn't -ErrorAction be used to log a timestamp for non-terminating errors?